# Expression creation on instance method without instance

Tags: .net, reflection, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a generic class that has a method 'Call' on it with a generic return type and a lambda expression as a parameter.  This has to be generated with reflection, and since the types are unknown, I need to create the lambda expression the long way.  I have a working solution listed below, but I do not like having to get the instance out of the generic class since it is private and does some logic on a retrieve.

Class:

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public TR Call<TR>(Func<T, TR> serviceInvoke)
    private T Instance
}
```

Reflection Usage:

```
var serviceInstance = proxy.GetType().GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(proxy, null);
var serviceMethod = type.GetMethod(rule.ServiceMethodName);
var parameters = serviceMethod.GetParameters().Select(parameterInfo => PropertyChainNavigator.GetValueForPropertyChain(((string)rule.Parameters[parameterInfo.Name]).Split(new[] { '.' }), context)).ToArray();
var thisParam = Expression.Constant(serviceInstance);
var valueParams = parameters.Select(Expression.Constant).ToList();
var call = Expression.Call(thisParam, serviceMethod, valueParams);
var func = Expression.Lambda(call, Expression.Parameter(type)).Compile();
var callMethod = proxy.GetType().GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Call" && x.ReturnType != typeof(void)).First().MakeGenericMethod(serviceMethod.ReturnType);
result = callMethod.Invoke(proxy, new[] { func });
```

Normal Usage:

```
var proxy = new Proxy<ITestClass>();
proxy.Call(x => x.Method);
```

I have tried to change the Expression.Call to not take an instance, but that only works on static methods. Does anyone know of a way for me to create the call, turn it into an lambda and have it compile without erroring

Comment: Why go through the headache of creating a lambda expression?  Why not just call it directly through Reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used lambda instead of expressions, your current code would look like this:

```
var serviceInstance = …; // retrieve using reflection
proxy.Call(i => serviceInstance.CallMethod(parameters));
```

Note that the lambda takes the parameter `i`, but doesn't use it. I assume you want to call the method directly on `i`, i.e. something like this:

```
proxy.Call(i => i.CallMethod(parameters));
```

To do that, use the value of `Expression.Parameter()` as `thisParam`:

```
var thisParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "i"); // the name is optional
var call = Expression.Call(thisParam, serviceMethod, valueParams);
var func = Expression.Lambda(call, thisParam).Compile();
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! you are a code saver!  The part I was missing while trying to get it to work was the last line 'Expression.Lambda(call, thisParam'. I had always kept it as 'Expression.Lambda(call, Expression.Parameter(type))' and that throws an error because it cannot understand what 'i' (or whatever I call the variable) is.

Comment: To further expand on why I couldn't just call 'proxy.Call(i => i.CallMethod(params));', the proxy was created using reflection as well and since the interface was generic typed as well, I did not have direct access to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public TR Call<TR>(Func<T, TR> serviceInvoke)
    {
        return serviceInvoke(Instance);
    }

    private T Instance;
}
```

Isn't this all you need?  Why should you need to get the `T` instance using reflection?

Comment: The code in the question *calls* the proxy, it's not the code inside it.